# Sql Server Managmenet Studio Alternative - Are there any?

Tags: software-rec, sql-server, sql-management-studio

I am looking for lightweight MS SQL Server Managmenet Studio (2005) alternative (open source/freeware is a bonus). Something more like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) for MySQL.

LINQPad is not an option (although it's great for learning Linq). It can only query database (and has many cons for my needs). I am looking for management/alteration functionality also, not only making queries and viewing the results.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "why" you're looking for an alternative? Different OS? Just hate SSMS?

Comment: I use HeidiSQL for MySql and the experience is not comparable to SSMS. I do the same thing quicker and easier in HeidiSQL for MySQL then in SSMS for MS SQL Server. In development industry we use such words as lightweight vs cumbersome to express this kind of difference without the need of enumerating the differences feature by feature. That why I think, that "lightweight alternative" should be enough :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on HeidiSQL -- I hadn't found that one yet and look forward to trying it out soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Quest Software's [Toad for SQL Server](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm). Free!

> Toad ™ for SQL Server Freeware is a
>   tool that improves the productivity of
>   developers and administrators by
>   providing an easy-to-use development
>   environment.
>
> With Toad, developers and database
>   administrators can use a familiar,
>   proven tool to manage SQL Server
>   databases. Quest Software has an
>   established track record for proven
>   solutions that simplify, automate and
>   improve the quality of application and
>   database development. You can rely on
>   Quest to provide you with an
>   intuitive, graphical tool with all the
>   features required to satisfy your
>   growing SQL Server needs.